# Is it okay to leave a Nissan Leaf for 6 months without driving it?

Tags: leaf

I think the short answer is yes.  Any thoughts about this?

BTW, page EV-5 in the 2017 Leaf owner's manual says:

```
While the vehicle is not in use
When the EV system is off for an extended time,
the 12-volt battery may be automatically charged
for a short period of time on a regular basis.
```

Comment: So what are you planning for the charging on a regular basis?

Comment: I am aware that the traction battery will slowly loose it's charge, at what rate it does this is one outstanding question I have.  Experience thus far is that the rate of loss is fairly low.  The car may need to be charged after 3 months.  I plan to have someone check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it's ok to do this.

We let our Leaf sit for over 6 months **without** being charged, but note well that we first unhooked the 12V battery while we were gone.

**The results:**  both the 12V and traction batteries were fine when we returned.  Neither had lost an appreciable amount of charge.

Answer (score 1):

The accessory battery for an EV "energizes" the electronics that manage the rest of the car. It's critical to keep the 12v battery healthy. A battery tender is highly recommended (not a trickle charger) as it maintains the battery at a safe level and doesn't try to push more electrons into it as time passes.

The main pack would be best placed at a storage voltage level, approximately 50 percent discharge or remaining power. Many of today's EVs will charge to 80% to reduce the stress on the pack at the top end of the charge. Our Rav4EV charges to 80% but allows "extended range" at the press of a few screen buttons. It also advises to not do this frequently.

Drive your EV half the usual distance, pop on a battery tender and you should not have to worry about the 3 month charge. If it does get charged, you'd have to also have it driven to drop off the top fifty percent to place it back into storage.

Alternatively, have the 3 month charge interrupted at a 50 percent full point.